# Mongodb aggretate apply sort to lookup results, and add field index number

Tags: mongodb, lookup

The aggregate was executed.

I got the results using lookup, but I need a sort.

In addition, I want to assign an index to the result value.

CollectionA :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6cf47415621604942386cd"),
    "contents" : [
             ObjectId("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"),
             ObjectId("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB")
    ],
    "name" : "jason"
}
```

CollectionB :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
    "title" : "a title",
    "date" : 2018-01-02
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB")
    "title" : "a title",
    "date" : 2018-01-01
}
```

Query:

```
db.getCollection('A').aggregate([
{
    $match : { "_id" : ObjectId("5a6cf47415621604942386cd") }
},
{
    $lookup : {
        from: "B",
        localField: "contents",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "item"

    }
},
{ $sort: { "item.date" : -1 } }
]);
```

Want Result:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6cf47415621604942386cd"),
        "contents" : [
         {
            "_id" : ObjectId("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB")
            "title" : "a title",
            "date" : 2018-01-01,
            "index" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
            "title" : "a title",
            "date" : 2018-01-02,
            "index" : 1
        }],
        "name" : "jason"
    }
```

> The current problem does not apply to the sort.
>
> And I don't know how to designate an index.

Answer (score 1):

Below [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) may you. For your desire result.

```
db.CollectionA.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { "_id": ObjectId("5a6cf47415621604942386cd") }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "CollectionB",
      let: { contents: "$contents" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$contents"] } }
        },
        { $sort: { date: 1 } }
      ],
      as: "contents"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      contents: {
        $map: {
          input: { $range: [0, { $size: "$contents" }, 1 ] },
          as: "element",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              { index: "$$element" },
              { $arrayElemAt: [ "$contents", "$$element" ]}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about it would be to unwind the array, sort it and then group it back

```
db.A.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a6cf47415621604942386cd")
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "B",
      localField: "contents",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "item"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$item"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "item.date": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      contents: {
        $push: "$item"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Another method is, (this is applicable only if the date field corresponds to the document creation date),

```
db.A.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a6cf47415621604942386cd")
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "B",
      localField: "contents",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "item"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "item": -1
    }
  }
])
```

Basically, this sorts on the basis of _id, and since _id is created using the creation date, it should sort accordingly.